# Can Swagger generate API if an Object A has references an ObjectB which references an ObjectA

Tags: java, swagger

I am attempting to build an API for my java web app using Swagger, RestEasy and annotations.

My api was growing nicely until tonight, when Swagger started getting stuck with message:

> fetching resource list...please wait.

This was after I added a method that returns type `ObjectA`, which has a field for type `ObjectB`, which contains a List of `ObjectA`'s.

Before I run off and try to write some half-baked workaround, I wonder if anyone has advice for troubleshooting this?  Am I trying something impossible?

Comment: could you please post the code for the said method?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to be on-topic: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: •the desired behavior, •a specific problem or error *and* •the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)